# How do I make a div change its width periodically using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a temperature scale (green up to some extent, then yellow and then red) in the background and need a temperature "bar" of sorts over it which:

1. Refreshes after a fixed interval of time, in the way that it "updates" itself periodically
2. Changes its width dynamically according to the parameters that it reads. For now I'm just trying to do it with a random number generator (within a range)

I did something like this, created a div here

```
<div id="temperatureBar" style="background-color: black; height: 20px;"></div>
```

and used some jQuery

```
function refreshTemperature(){
    var width = (Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#temperatureBar').fadeOut('slow');
        $(document).getElementById('temperatureBar').style.width = width+"px";
        $('#temperatureBar').fadeIn('slow');
        refreshTemperature();
    }, 5000);
}
```

This ain't working though. Can anyone help me with a workable solution?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get errors in the console? Is the result different from what you expect? If so, how is it different?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use `setInterval` and not `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `$.css` method of jquery.

Another thing which you may not have noiticed is that `setInterval` is called *every* 5 seconds in your code, and each call starts another `setInterval`.
This means that after a couple of minutes, you will have a **huge** number of events waiting to be called and this will lead to all sorts of problems. Use `setTimeout` instead.

*Here's a working sample:*

```js
function refreshTemperature() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = $('#temperatureBar')
    var width = (Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
    elem.fadeOut('slow');
    elem.css('width', width + "px");
    elem.fadeIn('slow');
    refreshTemperature();
  }, 5000);
}

refreshTemperature()
```

```css
#temperatureBar {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temperatureBar">
  My size changes
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated your js code. Now the width changes periodically.

```js
function refreshTemperature(){
    var width = (Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
     $('#temperatureBar').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#temperatureBar').css('width', width + "px");
        $('#temperatureBar').fadeIn('slow');            
}

setInterval(function () {        
    refreshTemperature();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temperatureBar" style="background-color: black; height: 20px;"></div>
```

Let me know if this is the desired result. 
Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. :)

Comment: Apologies for my earlier comment. Though it works for a while, if you let it run for like 2-3 minutes, it gets real flashy. Anything you could do to help with that?

Comment: You probably want `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. You might as well remove the whole `setInterval` thing in `refreshTemperature` and just do a single `setInterval` outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You never invoked `refreshTemperature()`, By the way, why not just use CSS instead over jQuery.

```css
.temp {
  min-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px grey;
  min-width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: color-swap 5s ease infinite;
  -ms-animation: color-swap 5s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: color-swap 5s ease infinite;
  animation: color-swap 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes color-swap {
  0% {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    min-width: 30px;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 50px;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: orange;
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="temp"></div>
```

Comment: I did call the function later in my base file, but your approach sure looks interesting. Thanks for this answer.